# Data variable picking wrong value itself

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

following is the code for binary search in a database.

```
int beg, mid, count = 0;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Dictionary.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select max(SNo) from WordList ", con);
con.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
int end;
while (dr.Read())
{
    end = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetValue(0));
}
con.Close();
beg = 0;
mid = (beg + end) / 2;

while (beg <= end)
{
```

my database has 140280 words in it.

the problem is that the variable **'end'** is itself getting divided by 2 itself if its value is >10958.

Can anyone tell, whats the issue?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at the `con.Close()` line, what value does `end` have at that time?

Comment: @AdamV at con.close() value of end is correct, after that something gets wrong.

Comment: You're not showing enough code then; none of your code shows `end` being changed beyond that line.

Comment: Ooh, stop using AttachDbFileName and User Instance. This combination is officially deprecated. Attach your database to a real instance of SQL Express, or use LocalDB.

Answer (score 1):

> my database has 140280 words in it.

I guess you are looking to get the `count` instead of `MAX`, the value you are getting in `end` is the MAX value for the field (`SNo`). Change your query to get `COUNT(SNo)`

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select COUNT(SNo) from WordList ", con);
```

Also use [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get a single value back. Consider enclosing your connection object and command object in  `using` statement.

```
int end = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: True, but in that case I'd think it'd be more likely to see an ID that was greater than the count than one that's lower.

Comment: @AdamV, I am not sure if it is an ID, it could hold duplicate values if it is not an ID

Comment: That's true, it doesn't have to be an ID. Regardless, using the `COUNT` is a more accurate way of getting the data the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Habib Count doesn't made any difference!

Comment: @BainuSingla, are you connecting to the correct database ? Also is SNo a primary key in the table ?